# Добавить проект без "запачкивания" решения

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Скажем, есть какое-то решение, которое хранится в TFS'е и там много всяких либ и т п вещей.

Так вот, допустим, я хочу протестировать работоспособность библиотеки и хочу создать консольный проект, что создать класс и вызвать методы.

Проблема в том, что в этом случае решение будет "запачканным" и на всем решении будет висеть значок, что я должен его закомитеть. Да, можно после эксперементов откатить солюшн, но про это можно забыть...

Можно ли это как-то избежать или для подобных экспериментов я должен открывать еще одну студию, там создавать мусорный проект и подключать интересующую себя либу?

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, создания проекта Вам не избежать. Можно открыть ещё одну студию, но это не удобно. Кроме того, использовать для тестирования обычный консольный проект не эффективно, да это и жёсткий костыль.

Для Вашей задаче гораздо больше подойдут юнит-тесты. Для их создания можно воспользоваться фреймворком, который идёт вместе со студией или каким-нибудь сторонним (например, NUnit).

Это позволит одновременно и протестировать библиотеку и не создавать лишних проектов, которые будут засорять решение ненужным функционалом.

Comment: Под тестированием я подразумевал "пощупать". Скажем в солюшене есть либа, которая возможно мне пригодится.

Comment: А что бы забрать соблюш себе и я не планирую изменения возвращать назад, то нужно анбинд сделать?

Comment: Если Вы не планируете ничего туда комиить просто не далйте этого или удалите связь с репозиторием. Как сделать последнее подсказать не смогу, т.к. с TFS давно не работал.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно стоит создать новый солюшн отдельно вне каталога, который замаплен локально с сервером, и просто добавить существующий на тфс ваш проект(ы) к нему.